# wamp ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED Localhost

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

Im on localhost on a newly reinstalled computer and hardrive, im trying to setup a website. everything works fine during the install, localhost as a web address works too.

However when i try to connect to one of my projects it gives me off this problem
"ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" I've been googling a lot and tried to find solutions that suits my problems but none of them seem to work.

wamp version: 3.1.3

[Picture of the site when i try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEitH.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was that the project was linking to http://wordpress/ and not http://localhost/wordpress/

Comment: No! The problem was that you did not create a Virtual Host to contain your WordPress site

Comment: No it already had a virtual host from the beginning. MY issue was that the link was taking me directly to wordpress instead of localhost/wordpress.

Virtual host was created. but it linked to the wrong address.

Comment: Ah so your Virtual Host was defined incorrectly. Fair enough